# Inserir no banco conforme os dados encontrados

Tags: php, sql

Estou com um certo problema em "lógica", onde eu devo inserir os registros de dois *arrays* em uma *table* do BD. Ai eu tenho a seguinte situação:

No primeiro `if` eu verifico se a `tabela_p` não contém dados. Caso não contenha, ela adiciona `null` na `tabela_p` e insere conforme quantos dados tiver a `tabela_s`;

```
if(count($tabela_p) == 0){
    $tabela_p = null;
    for( $i = 0; $i < count( $tabela_s); $i ++ ) {

        $w_querybusca="insert into sai_cad_patr_seri (fk_seq_cara_peri,tx_num_patr,tx_num_seri)
                  values ('$arr_w_param[17]','$tabela_p[$i]','$tabela_s[$i]');"; 

        $w_queryresultado = f_class_conecta_bd($w_querybusca);          
    }
}
else
{
    for( $i = 0; $i < count($tabela_p); $i ++ ) {
        $w_querybusca="insert into sai_cad_patr_seri (fk_seq_cara_peri,tx_num_patr,tx_num_seri)
                  values ('$arr_w_param[17]','$tabela_p[$i]','$tabela_s[$i]');";                       
        $w_queryresultado = f_class_conecta_bd($w_querybusca);          
    }       
}
```

Logo no `else` eu insiro conforme a `tabela_p`; O problema é:

- Caso tenha um valor na `tabela_p` ele cai no `else` e ira executar o for somente uma vez. Mas tem a possibilidade de conter 2 ou mais dados na `tabela_s` ai ele não vai inserir eles.

Como eu deveria fazer para arrumar essa lógica?

Comment: Você percebe que existem alguns erros no código?
Por exemplo, no primeiro if, onde a variável $tabela_p é setada como null, logo abaixo você faz um for, utilizando o $i para índice da variável $tabela_p, isso vai gerar um erro.

Outra coisa, acredito que ficaria mais simples e legível o código caso trocasse os **for's** por **foreach's**

Answer (score 1):

Você usa o `p` como parâmetro do `for`. Use o `s`, já que você quer que o `s` defina o loop.

Troque

```
for( $i = 0; $i < count($tabela_p); $i ++ )
```

por

```
for( $i = 0; $i < count($tabela_s); $i ++ )
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer 2 algo parecido com:

Caso você sempre tenha certeza que irá existir valor na variável **$tabela_s**, então basta apenas 1 **foreach**.

```
foreach ($tabela_s as $key_s => $value_s){
        foreach ($tabela_p as $key_s=> $value_p){
            $w_querybusca="insert into sai_cad_patr_seri (fk_seq_cara_peri,tx_num_patr,tx_num_seri) values ('$arr_w_param[17]',$value_p,'$value_s;"; 
            $w_queryresultado = f_class_conecta_bd($w_querybusca);          
        }
    }
```